# In iis 8- getting error request is not available in this context

Tags: iis, iis-8

When running asp.net website in iis 8 in integrated mode then getting error Request is not available in this context

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis#16-it-is-not-possible-to-access-the-request-through-the-httpcontextcurrent-property-in-applicationstart-in-globalasax

Answer (score 0):

IIS integrated mode will return this error when you are trying to process request context in application_start. IIS integrated mode will block the code when HideRequestResponse flag is set to true in application_start. It is totally by design. So it is recommended to not use request context in application_start. If access request context in application context is necessary for you, please host the code in try{ }..catch{ } or keep using classic mode.